# Extjs - JavaScript - Combo with Templates - Multiple values as a displayfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, autocomplete

I am working on Extjs 4.1. I did implement an autocomplete feature for the text box.I would like to customize the displayfield to display multiple values instead of one. I tried convert function:

```
Ext.define("Post", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'app/search/autocomplete.php',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'names',
        autoLoad: true,
        totalProperty: 'totalCount'
    },
    fields: ['f_name','l_name', {
        name : 'display',
        convert : function(v, rec) {                        
            return rec.f_name + ' ' + rec.l_name
        }
    }]
});
```

but I got: `undefined undefined` in the text box!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab the property:

`return rec.get('f_name') + ' ' + rec.get('l_name');`